# What does token mean?

Tags: authentication, token

I always hear the word token, eg. request a token.

I usually replace that word with "key".

But what does it mean exactly?

Comment: Great Question because i was preparing to ask totally same question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A token is a unit of information (as opposed to a unit of data witch could be an integer). It is the smallest chunk of data that composes information.

for instance, in a compiler tokenizer, the char array {'c', 'l', 'a', 's', 's'} would be a chunk of data composing the token "class" (Because a complete word is, in most cases, the smallest kind of information a compiler deals with).

Comment: Am I missing something or does this have nothing to do with an authentication token (which is what the OP indicated he was looking for)?

Comment: The OP gave an example. I don't think an example should be taken so strictly.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what kind of "token" you're talking about.

If you're talking about a hardware token, it's a piece of hardware that gives each user an identification number. That number is then paired with their username/password to provide an extra level of authentication.

If you're talking about a software token, then it's simply a piece of identifying information that is given to you after you authenticate with a system.

Once you have a token, you can provide that token to the authentication system to prove that you're already an authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

http://computer.yourdictionary.com/token

> In authentication systems, a hardware
>   device (e.g., smart card,
>   calculator-line device, or flash
>   drive), or software on a client
>   computer, that stores the user's
>   credentials and generates a one-time
>   password. The authentication process
>   commonly involves a challenge-response
>   dialogue between the token and a
>   dedicated authentication server. In
>   conjunction with a personal
>   identification number (PIN) and
>   supplemental password, a token is an
>   excellent security mechanism. See also
>   authentication, password, and
>   security.